# Do 1's (fumbles) for gatling guns count before or after the wild die?

Tags: savage-worlds, deadlands-reloaded, shooting

In Savage Worlds Deluxe / Deadlands reloaded, when rolling an attack with a gatling gun, do you check for the bad things that happen on one/many natural 1s before or after you exchange a shooting die with the wild die?

According to the information on pg. 46 & 53 in the Deadlands Player Handbook I would assume you can't use the wild die to cancel a bad 1 on the skill dice in case of gatling guns ... right?

Comment: Maybe add the chapters instead of the page numbers, as the Exlorers edition is layed out differently and has other page numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fumbles only come into play once it's been established that you have missed.**

The order in which you apply the stages are as follows:

- Roll a number of dice equal to the ROF of the weapon and an additional Wild Die.
- Calculate how many hits you have. If the Wild Die is a hit then you can substitute that for a miss on one of the Shooting dice.
- If you have any misses then look to see if you rolled any 1's
- If you missed with any shots and rolled no 1s then there is no fumble
- If you missed with any shots and rolled at least a single 1 then you have a fumble

For example, lets say you are firing your ROF3 gun with 3d8 and a d6. The d8s come up 5,5,1 and the Wild Die comes up with a 7. Due to the -2 penalty for firing full auto, the 3d8s all miss. However, you can substitute the result of the hit result on the Wild Die for the 1, meaning that you hit with all three shots and there is no fumble.

Let's take a second example, same dice but the results are 5,5,1 and a 3 for the Wild Die. Again, you have 2 hits with the Shooting Die. However, this time the Wild Die is also a miss, so overall you have one miss. As you rolled a 1 and you missed, you fumble.

See [here](https://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17289&highlight=innocent%20bystander%20rof), [here](https://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=30192&highlight=innocent%20bystander%20rof), [here](https://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=29788&highlight=innocent%20bystander) for confirmation of this.

Comment: Based on the references, I would be convinced for single 1's on "regular" gatling weapons. However the "more 1's than anything else" for RoF-3 gatling guns is still only 90% sure for me.

Comment: Is that clearer?

Answer (score 4):

Deadland reloaded says:

> If the shooter rolls more 1’s than anything
>   else in a single burst, the weapon jams and does not
>   operate until a Repair roll is made.

Normally the Savage World rules say *Shooting Skill Dice* if you can't replace it with a *Wild Die*.

So I would say after.

Comment: I've learned when it comes to SW+Deadlands quotes, there is often an additional sentence somewhere else with new information. So this cite is useful, but not yet 100% convincing for me.